# How to turn on bottom tool window with views in IntelIj Idea?

Tags: intellij-idea

[image: botton tool window]

I somehow closed this and now if i need t o switch between terminal and run i need to restart whole project. It is dumb question but how can i return this line with 'run/todo/terminal' ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Window -> Restore Default Layout

Or, with the keyboard shortcut `Shift + F12`.

Edit:

Make sure this is checked.

> View -> Appearance -> Tool Window Bars

Comment: no, it just closed everything. I need to turn ON , not off this bottom line.

Comment: @Ars Don't they turn "on" when you click on one of them?
Or perhaps, try dragging them to the top to increase their size.

Comment: @Ars View -> Appearance -> Tool Window Bars

Comment: i dont have 'appearance' in View